# Azure B2C Custom Policy Create User With Multipe signIn Email Addresses

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am trying to create user using Azure AD Custom Policies, with two email addresses, using the signIn.emailAddress claim, but it looks like this is a string field and is overwritten by the 2nd value. It creates the user, but only with on signIn email address, not two.

For example, the xml has two persisted claims that both target the signIn.emailAddress, but only 2nd value is saved, as it overwrites the first, only the value of claim "secondEmail" is saved:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="AzureActiveDirectory-CreateUser">       
  <InputClaims>          
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInEmail" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" />                       
  </InputClaims>        
  <PersistedClaims>            
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInEmail" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" />            
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="secondEmail" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" />        
  </PersistedClaims>        
  <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AzureActiveDirectory-CreateUserAsLocalAccount" />  
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Is there any way of creating a user with two signIn email addresses?

Thanks

I have tried the above example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to have:

- signInNames.emailAddress
- signInNames.emailAddress1

as per [this](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/using-identities-and-linking-them-in-azure-ad-b2c-33b72fcbfd25).

Comment: This worked me setting, and appreciate the linked document, it explains this is good detail.